# Multiple argument bash script for awk processing

Tags: bash, awk

Is there a way to process 2 different files passed as arguments to a bash script which uses awk.

Script signature:

```
./statistical_sig.sh path_to_reviews_folder hotel_1 hotel_2
```

I tried the following but only the first argument got processed.

```
hotel1="$2";
hotel2="$3";

dos2unix -U $hotel1 | dos2unix -U $hotel2 | echo "$hotel1" "$hotel2" | xargs | awk -v hotel1="$hotel1" -v hotel2="$hotel2" { .. code ..}
```

Comment: Please explain bit more, what are you trying to do ? why so many pipe

Comment: None of what you have written makes any sense :(  Firstly, not sure which dos2unix you are using, but I cannot find a -U option.  Then, as above, what would be the purpose of piping the information from one dos2unix command into another, there is but a single line of output from a successful call which would not help the following call in anyway.  Next we have a random echo ... to achieve what? xargs gets to play with nothing but 2 strings which it will do what with? And lastly an incomplete awk which uses the same 2 variables inside the script, that we can't see.

Comment: I am doing my coursework and I have to change the formatting of the files I am processing otherwise it won't work when they mark my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all these pipes to run awk.

Either you will use something like this if you plan to read with awk some other files and use hotel1 and hotel2 somehow inside your awk code:

```
awk -v hotel1=$(dos2unix -U "$hotel1") -v hotel2=$(dos2unix -U "$hotel2") { awk code ..} file1 file2
```

Or you will use this if you plan to read and process contents of files hotel1 and hotel2:

```
awk { awk code ..} <(dos2unix -U "$hotel1") <(dos2unix -U "$hotel2")
```

Alternativelly you can modify your code like this, but this is less efficient :

```
hotel1=$(dos2unix "$hotel1") && hotel2=$(dos2unix "$hotel2") && echo "$hotel1 $hotel2" | awk '{your code here}'
```

If you explain better your question advising what is the awk code and what you are trying to achieve, you will get better advises.

Comment: @Radoslav Add to the end one or more of 2>&1 or >/dev/null or  2>/dev/null